# Custom header and footer in TCPDF with WhiteOctober Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF for creating PDF files in my Symfony2 application and I would like to change the way header and footer is generated. I have integrated the class as service by using WhiteOctober Bundle. So is there any way how to change header and footer functions within this bundle? If not, how should I use and customize TCPDF otherwise?

The only possibility for customizing this bundle seem to be changing Configuration.php file, but there are defined only TCPFD constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a own class that extends the TCPDF class. Override the methods `Header()` and `Footer()` to define your custom header and footer. If you need different headers and footers for example front pages you can check for page numbers and so on.

After implementing the class, use your custom class as service.